# How to revert / cancel git reset --soft HEAD~20

Tags: git, revert, git-reset

I wanted to squash few commits and I followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git). So I did:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~20
git commit
git push -f
```

I don't know why but now my branch full of merging which wasn't before. I want to revert the `git reset --soft HEAD~20` command. How can it be done?

### Update

I did: `git reset < commit hash` before the reset: moving to HEAD~20 >
then `git push` and I'm getting:

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://xxxx@bitbucket.org/xxxx/xxxx.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: You can try using `git reflog` to get the sha-1 for the commit which you want your HEAD to point to . And then its `git reset --hard <commit-hash>` to restore your branch back to that commit.

Comment: why i need the "--hard" ? do i need to git push to also ?

Comment: If you had any local changes and you don't want those changes again in your repo, you can use --hard option . It just brings the repo back to a state it was at the specified commit.

Comment: please see update question im getting error

Comment: I think you need to force push again `git push origin <your_branch_name> --force` . I hope no-one else is pulling changes from your branch , as I see you already did force push once before.

Comment: Your second issue is a regular issue when your local branch has forked from the remote branch. Check your local history vs the remote history, and decide wether you should `push --force`, `merge`, `rebase` ...

Comment: Did resetting to that hash in the reflog solve your initial issue ? If so, you can mark @meshkati's answer as accepted.

Comment: FYI, don't forget to prefer `--force-with-lease` whenever you can...

Comment: @user63898 maybe another dev has pushed something in the remote branch, since the commit you diverged (pull)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run:

```
git reflog
```

It will show you something like  this:

```
0475497 (HEAD -> master) HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to HEAD~20
ab155bc HEAD@{1}: commit: commit before reset
5da1f69 HEAD@{2}: commit: commit message
c2d9604 HEAD@{3}: commit: commit message
.
.
.
```

Then you can checkout or reset to the commit before reset, by using its commit hash ( in the above example, it's `ab155bc` )

Comment: so to do : git reset ab155bc